# How to update the Status of all user specified no of students in merit list in stored procedure

Tags: sql-server

I have created a stored procedure which calculates the Merit on the basis of student marks of user specified no of students.

Table: **tblStdApplyDetail**

```
ID (INT): 1
Name (varchar): Yousra
FormNo (INT): 6802
Status (BIT): 0
```

Table two : **StdAcadmiaDetail**

```
stdapp_ref_id (INT): 1
totalmatrix (INT): 1100
obtainedmatrix (INT): 936
totalfa (INT): 1100
obtainedfa (INT): 973
obtSubjMarks (INT): 177
totalSubjMarks (INT): 200
YOP (INT): 2017
PreferredSubjMarks (INT): 0
HafizQuran (INT): 0
```

And the result should be:

```
Name   | FormNo   | Merit %
-------+----------+-------------
Yousra | 6802     | 87.87
```

And also update the `Status` of `StdApplyDetail` table:

```
ID  | Name  |  FormNo  | Status
----+-------+----------+--------
 1  | Yousra|  6802    |  1
```

Here is my stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[BSMeritCalculator]
    (@NoOfStudents AS INT)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @YOP INT

    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SET ROWCOUNT @NoOfStudents

    SELECT 
        A.Name, A.FormNo,
        CASE ISNULL(D.YOP, 0) 
           WHEN ('2017') 
              THEN (ISNULL(D.obtainedmatrix, 0) / 4 + ISNULL(D.obtainedfa, 0) + ISNULL(D.obtSubjMarks, 0) + ISNULL(D.HafizQuran, 0) + ISNULL(D.PreferredSubjMarks, 0)) * 100 / (CAST((ISNULL(D.totalmatrix, 0) / 4) AS FLOAT(1)) + ISNULL(D.totalfa, 0) + ISNULL(D.totalSubjMarks, 0)) 
           WHEN ('2016') 
              THEN (ISNULL(D.obtainedmatrix, 0) / 4  + ISNULL(D.obtainedfa, 0) + ISNULL(D.obtSubjMarks, 0) + ISNULL(d.HafizQuran, 0) + ISNULL(D.PreferredSubjMarks, 0) - 2) * 100 / (CAST((ISNULL(D.totalmatrix, 0) / 4) AS FLOAT(1)) + ISNULL(D.totalfa, 0) + ISNULL(D.totalSubjMarks, 0)) 
           WHEN ('2015')
              THEN ''
        END AS [Merit %]
    FROM 
        StdApplyDetail A
    JOIN 
        StdAcadmiaDetail D ON A.id = D.stdapp_ref_id
    WHERE 
        A.Status = 0
    ORDER BY 
        [Merit %] DESC

    SET ROWCOUNT 0;
END
```

Now I want to update the status of all top ranked merit students in the list from 0 to 1 to prevent the name in 2nd merit list. I don't know how to use update query in the procedure.

Please guide me.

Comment: Sample data as DDL+DML and desired results, please.

Comment: please check the updated post.

Comment: DDL - create table statements. DML - insert into statements.

Comment: Question is still unclear.   What makes a student "top ranked"?  Which students should be updated from 0 to 1, which should not, and why?

Comment: @TabAlleman students who have the highest merit after calculation of marks are top ranked students. I want to update based on select query like at the time of select and merit calculation only the status of students with the highest merit will update

Answer (score 0):

In that case, I used temp table and write update statement for status update and then select it from temp table.